# Observer on reissuing cash results into Error "java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate."

Tags: corda

I have setup corda network as below:

2 Bank Nodes

1 CentralBank Node(Observer)

1 Notary

I have issued cash from CentralBank to each Bank nodes.
For issuing cash used "CashIssueAndPaymentFlow". I can issue cash to same node multiple times too.

Then try to perform transaction from one Bank node to other bank node where CentralBank is observer.

After transaction completion, when I try to issue cash to any bank nodes, gives below error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
        at net.corda.node.services.keys.PersistentKeyManagementService.getSigningKeyPair(PersistentKeyManagementService.kt:110) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.keys.PersistentKeyManagementService.sign(PersistentKeyManagementService.kt:101) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.toSignedTransaction(TransactionBuilder.kt:224) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:219) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:233) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.signInitialTransaction(AbstractNode.kt:836) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.node.ServiceHub$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHub.kt:255) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.signInitialTransaction(ServiceHubInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.signInitialTransaction(AbstractNode.kt:836) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashPaymentFlow.call(CashPaymentFlow.kt:66) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashPaymentFlow.call(CashPaymentFlow.kt:26) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.call(CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.kt:41) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.call(CashIssueAndPaymentFlow.kt:24) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
```

In simple words, Cash issued from CentralBank and also keep CentralBank as Observer. After few transaction, again try to issue cash gives above error.

Corda version used for above thing is V3.3.

Provide some guidance on same.

Comment: hi - I have the same issue but with no observer involved.

flow: settle flow, 1 input state and 1 cash state to pay full amount.

Comment: hi, cash is issued using IssueRequest or CashIssueAndPaymentFlow? Is it self issued cash or any other node is issuing it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that an issue flow would fail when running it the second time. 
Have you modified the auction cordapp very much? Also, can you share the steps you used to make this happen?

Are you able to reproduce this on the latest version of Corda?

For anyone wondering, the code example being referred to here seems to be this one : https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp